# Simulate Ajax Call with Scrapy

Tags: ajax, http, post, scrapy

i'm new at scraping with Scrapy and unfortunatly, i can't access data through a request (to simulate an AJAX request made).
I read others topics, but it didnt help me resolve my issues.
The website i would like to crawl is [auchan.fr](https://www.auchandirect.fr/recherche) ,it has a dynamic search box driven by algolia ([algolia](https://www.algolia.com/)).

Here is my spider for a Nutella request(POST then):

```
class AjaxspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "ajaxspider"
allowed_domains = ["auchandirect.fr/recherche"]
#start_urls = ['https://www.auchandirect.fr/recherche/']

def start_requests(self):
    full_url = "/1/indexes/articles_article_11228/query?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%203.20.4&x-algolia-application-id=TN96V7LRXC&x-algolia-api-key=46a121512cba9c452df318ffca231225"
    yield FormRequest('https://tn96v7lrxc-dsn.algolia.net' + full_url, callback=self.parse, formdata={"params":"query=nutella&facets=%5B%22loopr_shelf%22%5D&hitsPerPage=50"})

def parse(self, response):
    with open('data_content', 'w') as file:
        file.write(response.content)
```

and Here is the log i got :

```
    2017-02-03 15:14:34 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.0 started (bot: ajax)
2017-02-03 15:14:34 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'SPIDER_MODULES': ['ajax.spiders'], 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'ajax.spiders', 'BOT_NAME': 'ajax'}
2017-02-03 15:14:34 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-02-03 15:14:34 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-02-03 15:14:34 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-02-03 15:14:34 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-02-03 15:14:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-02-03 15:14:34 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-02-03 15:14:34 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-02-03 15:14:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://tn96v7lrxc-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/articles_article_11228/query?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%203.20.4&x-algolia-application-id=TN96V7LRXC&x-algolia-api-key=46a121512cba9c452df318ffca231225> (referer: None)
2017-02-03 15:14:35 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://tn96v7lrxc-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/articles_article_11228/query?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%203.20.4&x-algolia-application-id=TN96V7LRXC&x-algolia-api-key=46a121512cba9c452df318ffca231225>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2017-02-03 15:14:35 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-02-03 15:14:35 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 545,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 338,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/400': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 3, 14, 14, 35, 216807),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 3, 14, 14, 34, 977436)}
2017-02-03 15:14:35 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

i thank you for any piece for informations

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: my spider is closed even before it went to the parse function, due to the the request i guess, so i cant parse the return of my request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Ajax-related but site-specific question, you just passes search parameters string wrong way trying to pass it as `formdata` while it should be passed as raw body of `POST` request, so it should be like that:

```
yield Request('https://tn96v7lrxc-dsn.algolia.net' + full_url,
              callback=self.parse, method='POST',
              body='{"params":"query=nutella&facets=%5B%22loopr_shelf%22%5D&hitsPerPage=50"}')
```